# Creating an instance in aws using red hat satellite?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I need to deploy an instance in aws, and manage/provision the instance from Red Hat Satellite. Can I do it from the satellite itself? Or should I import the created instance as a managed host?

If I did try to deploy the instance from Red Hat satellite in AWS (assuming that vpc connections are already done), can I see the instance being deployed in AWS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.